# Select at most one number from each set so that the sum of selected numbers equals a given number

Tags: optimization, combinations

I have a such a problem and I wonder whether there is an suitable model in Combinatorial Optimization or Operations Research. The question is: I have several sets of integers, and a given integer `N`. Select at most 1 integer from each set so that the sum of selected integers equals `N`.
If there is no suitable models for this, how to write this problem efficiently into a integer programming problem? Thanks!

I tried the Subset sum problem which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a specifically designed algorithm for this problem. Here is a possible ILP formulation: Let x_{ij} be 1 if the ith element of set j is chosen, and 0 otherwise. The parameter a_{ij} is the value of the integer. We want to minimize the number of selected elements to attain N.

[image]